# Is msync atomic?

Tags: c, unix, memory-mapping

When using `mmap`/`msync`/`munmap`, are the read/write atomic? (assuming the disk will finish any pending writes when powering down)

Answer (score 2):

Operations that involve multiple pages or multiple disk sectors are never precisely atomic.

It might be more useful to investigate *coherency* between two specific things.

For example, between two programs or threads that are both *mmap(2)*-ing the same file, they are already coherent and `msync(2)` is unrelated to this. All `msync` does is cause the kernel to write modified pages *to the underlying storage system* ... it is not necessary or helpful with respect to other readers and writers on the same system also using *mmap()*.

If you want to use a different facility (shared storage or non-mmap I/O) and synchronize access, you will need a real semaphore or interlock. I don't think msync() can be useful. To give you more help we would need to know more about what you are trying to synchronize.